# export 'withRouter' (imported as 'withRouter') was not found in 'react-router-dom'. using react-router-dom: 6.0.2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I can't roll back to previous versions of React, how should I overcome this error?

```
import { Component } from 'react' ;

import { withRouter} from "react-router-dom";

class ScrollToTop extends Component {
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0)
      }
    }
  
    render() {
      return this.props.children
    }
  }
  
  export default withRouter(ScrollToTop)
```

Comment: React Router 6 has moved over to hooks and function-based components, if you need a HOC just _write one_.

Comment: RRDv6 removed the `withRouter` HOC, if you still need one you'll need to [create it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64566486/8690857) or convert to React function components to use the React hooks directly. Or create a [`ScrollToTop`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65710997/8690857) component.